# Generalized Inverse Property

Tags: linear-algebra

For any non-singular matrix $A$ let $A^{-1}$ represents its inverse matrix. Now we do the following,
$A^{-1}=(A^{-1})^{\frac{1}{2}}(A^{-1})^{\frac{1}{2}}$.
My question is for the generalized inverse of a matrix $A$, that is $A^{+}$ can we do the following?

$A^{+}=(A^{+})^{\frac{1}{2}}(A^{+})^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $A^{-1/2}$? I suspect that what you're trying to say is simply that "for any non-singular matrix $A$, there exists a matrix $B$ such that $A^{-1} = B^2$". Is that correct?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I feel that's what he means is that generally true?

Comment: @BenGrossmann thanks for your kind comment. yes, I want to know that.

Comment: In case of real $1\times 1$ matrices this is false. The matrix $[-1]$ is not a square.  On the other hand every complex square matrix is a square.  This may be proved by employing the analytic functional calculus which one learns in Functional Analysis.

Comment: However the square root of a matrix is not unique so the notation $A^{1/2}$ doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Ruy Every **invertible** complex matrix is square (i.e. has a square root). For example, the matrix 
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$
has no square root over any field.

Comment: Ops! @BenGrossmann is right and I'm wrong.  To apply the analytical functional calculus one needs the spectrum of $A$ to lie in the open domain of some continuous branch of $\sqrt\cdot$ and that for sure excludes zero!

Answer (score 2):

The question that you're asking is as follows.

> Is it true that for every square matrix $A$, there exists a matrix $B$ such that $B^2 = A^+$? That is, does $A^+$ always have a square root?

I also assume that by $A^+$, you refer specifically to the [Moore Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Definition) rather than an actual (otherwise unspecified) [generalized inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse).

The answer to that question is no. For example, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0} \implies A^+ = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}.
$$
There exists no matrix $B$ for which $B^2 = A^+$.